# How to use jQuery find() function with CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to do something similar to [Cabybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) within function in CasperJS. I want to get parent divs and retrieve text from their child elements.

Something like this:

```
$('div.education').find('h4').text()
$('div.education').find('h1').text()
```

Code snippet is as follows:

```
casper.page.injectJs('/jquery-latest.min.js');
var links = casper.evaluate(function() {
    var elements = $('div.education');
    return elements.map(function(e){
           this.fetchText(casper.evaluate(function(){
                return e.find('h4.summary');
           }));
           this.fetchText(casper.evaluate(function(){
                return e.find('h1');
           }));
    });
});
casper.echo(links);
```

Currently its returning `null`. How to achieve this in CasperJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div.education').find('h4')
```

should be functionally equivalent to the CSS selector

```
'div.education h4'
```

If you want to fetch the text from those nodes, you can use [`casper.fetchText()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fetchtext), but it will concatenate all text into a single string. Another useful function is [`casper.getElementsInfo()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsinfo) because it already provides the text property:

```
casper.then(function(){
    var h4Texts = this.getElementsInfo('div.education h4').map(function(h4){
        return h4.text;
    });
    var h1Texts = this.getElementsInfo('div.education h1').map(function(h1){
        return h1.text;
    });
    // do something with h4Texts and h1Texts
});
```

This has the h4 and h1 texts in two different lists for the same parent element which may not be what you want. You can still use CasperJS' functions to achieve having h4 and h1 texts together using the XPath support of CasperJS:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.then(function(){
    var parents = this.getElementsInfo('div.education');
    var result = parents.map(function(divInfo, i){
        var h4Texts = this.getElementsInfo(x('(//div[contains(@class,'education')])['+(i+1)+']//h4')
            .map(function(h4){
                return h4.text;
            });
        var h1Texts = this.getElementsInfo(x('(//div[contains(@class,'education')])['+(i+1)+']//h1')
            .map(function(h1){
                return h1.text;
            });
        return {h1: h1Texts, h4: h4Texts};
    });

    var h1Texts = this.getElementsInfo('div.education h1').map(function(h1){
        return h1.text;
    });
    // do something with `result`
});
```

Description:

- `//div[contains(@class,'education')]` returns the node list of parent elements,
- `(//div[contains(@class,'education')])['+(i+1)+']` takes the `i+1`-th parent (counting starts at 1) and
- `(//div[contains(@class,'education')])['+(i+1)+']//h1` and `(//div[contains(@class,'education')])['+(i+1)+']//h4` finds the h1 and h4 descendants of the same parent.

---

You have multiple problems with your code.

The filename in `casper.page.injectJs('/jquery-latest.min.js');` should be either `'./jquery-latest.min.js'` or `'jquery-latest.min.js'` jquery is in the same directory as your CasperJS script.

Then it seems that you didn't understand the difference between page context and outer casper context. The [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) function is the sandboxed page context. It has the limitations that variables have to be explicitly passed into it (read [this](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) completely) and usually `this` refers to `window` of the page and not `casper`. In your case you use `this` inside of the `map` callback which will refer to the jQuery object of the DOM node and not `casper`. Also, jQuery doesn't have a `.fetchText()` function, so it will produce an error. `casper` is also not available in the page context, but you can use the [`__utils__` module](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html).

So you could've written the script like this:

```
casper.page.injectJs('jquery-latest.min.js');
var links = casper.evaluate(function() {
    var elements = $('div.education');
    return elements.map(function(){
        return {
            h4: $(this).find('h4.summary').map(function(){
                return $(this).text();
            }),
            h1: $(this).find('h1').map(function(){
                return $(this).text();
            })
        };
    });
});
casper.echo(links);
```

Finally, to make sure that you see all the problems, register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events:

```
casper.on("remote.message", function(msg){
    this.echo("remote.msg: " + msg);
});

casper.on("page.error", function(pageErr){
    this.echo("page.err: " + JSON.stringify(pageErr));
});
```

Comment: I'm relatively new to CasperJS.Scope of objects & functions are not clearly stated in the documentation.Thanks for the detailed explanation.This is what i really needed.This clears lot of things.

Comment: I get this error "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'e.find('h4.summary')')" when i execute the above snippet. jQuery library is included in the script.Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks, jQuery has a strange `map` syntax. I fixed it using `$(this)`. Why do you want to use jQuery? The approach with the native CasperJS functions is much cleaner.

Comment: Does CasperJS functions support this?Basically,I want to chain the locators.(i.e something like parentElement.find(childElement). Why i want to do this way ,because i have multiple parent elements and this let me avoid using indexes.otherwise,i need to provide complete css path in all child elements along with index(something like this parent:nth-of-type(index) child).That is the main reason i chose to go with jQuery.

Comment: I don't see why you need indexes or a complete CSS path. But then you haven't provided your sample HTML and what form you want your results to be in. Since you haven't specified this, my answer shows a possible solution. Btw, I have just fixed the jQuery solution. It's not possible to have two returns in a function.

Comment: Atrjom - your solution solves my problem.I'm asking you an additional question, is there way to do it using CasperJS functions as you have mentioned in your previous comment.

Comment: Yes, but I think you would have to use the XPath support of CasperJS instead of CSS selectors with specific type of expression. I'll provided code for this too.

Comment: When i try to print Links,its printing as "object Object" and not the actual value.I assumed it to be array of maps,and tried Links[0]["h4"].even this returns object.Is my understanding correct?what am i missing?

Comment: `Links[0].h4` is also an array. So, check `Links[0].h4.length` before accessing `Links[0].h4[0]`. If there is only one `h4`-`h1` pair in a `div` then you can change the code to directly return the element text instead of mapping the elements to their text.